# Create a custom data and data loader object in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

my dataset is of this form, I want to create data and dataloader in pytorch on my final_train_data, final_test_data, final_train_label, final_test_label. I want to divide my data into 2 batches. Can you tell me, how can I create?

```
train_data = t.randn(12, 12)
test_data = t.randn(6,6)
train_label = t.randn(12, 12)
test_label = t.randn(6, 6)
train_data1 = t.randn(12, 12)
test_data1 = t.randn(6,6)
train_label1 = t.randn(12, 12)
test_label1 = t.randn(6, 6)



final_train_data = [train_data, train_data1]
final_test_data = [test_data, test_data1]
final_train_label = [train_label, train_label1]
final_test_label = [test_label, test_label1]
```

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html This explains how to make custom Datasets. You can then just call on Dataloader to create dataloaders.